# how to use this URL to sync time android

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl

i have a url given to me to used for syncing the server time to my application, 
Question is how to do that? anyone can explain to me what to do here thank i really appreciate it.

here's the URL = http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc/CurrentTime

here is my mainactivity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Timer timeoutTimer;
    final Random myRandom = new Random();
    GenerateTask genTask = new GenerateTask();
    static String RAN_TEXT = "text";

    class GenerateTask extends TimerTask {
        boolean started = false;
        public void run() {
            if (started) {
                System.out.println("generating");
                final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);
                RAN_TEXT = "";

                for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                    RAN_TEXT += myRandom.nextInt(10) + " ";
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textGenerateNumber.setText(RAN_TEXT);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateme);

        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("click");
                if (!genTask.started) {
                    genTask.started=true;
                    timeoutTimer = new Timer();
                    timeoutTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(genTask, 0, 30000);
                } else {
                    genTask.started=false;
                    timeoutTimer.cancel();
                }
            }
       });  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you gave returns XML file, that does not have anything resembling time inside, you'd better ask for another URL or the explanation from the people who gave you this one:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="TimeService" targetNamespace="TimeService">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="TimeService/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="TimeService"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="ITimeService_GetCurrentDateTime_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCurrentDateTime"/>
</wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="ITimeService_GetCurrentDateTime_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCurrentDateTimeResponse"/>
</wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="ITimeService">
<wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentDateTime">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="TimeService/ITimeService/GetCurrentDateTime" message="tns:ITimeService_GetCurrentDateTime_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="TimeService/ITimeService/GetCurrentDateTimeResponse" message="tns:ITimeService_GetCurrentDateTime_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITimeService" type="tns:ITimeService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetCurrentDateTime">
<soap:operation soapAction="TimeService/ITimeService/GetCurrentDateTime" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input><wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="TimeService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITimeService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ITimeService">
<soap:address location="http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc/basicHttpBinding"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: what would be the right url for time server? i will ask them but i need know what is the right url to use as you said the URL just they gave just return XML. can you give me an example of URL/WSDL link for time server?

Comment: hello lenik they gave me a new URL please see above i already updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is a link to a WSDL file, which describe how you could use their Web Service to get the time. You need to use some kind of tools to generate the Web Service to get the time, such as Apache CXF. However, as you are talking about Android, that would be too heavy weight...

Comment: is there a way to generate the webservice to get the time and sync it to my application?

Comment: For invoking that webservice, so you could get the time from it, instead of using some Web Service library, you may try to craft the HTTP request and send it out. For the SOAP envelope, you may generate that with this: http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html. Then, send an HTTP POST request with the XML generated.